# Import certificates in Tomcat

Tags: certificates, tomcat

I have some difficulty to import our `*.example.com` certificate. I have the following files:

```
"<something>.crt" 
"<something>.csr" and 
"<something>.key".
```

So what I need is to import this certificate in our stash atlassian service that is running on Tomcat. Any idea how to do this as I try any stuff with keytools etc.? We already have one certificate implemented but it reaches end of life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find where your Tomcat's keystore file is.  This is usually configured via a `<Connector>` element in the [Tomcat config](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File), *e.g.*:

```
<Connector ...
  keystore="/path/to/keystore.jks"
</Connector>
```

Since you mentioned you already have an existing certificate that's about to expire, it suggests that you already do have a keystore configured like this.

So then, we need to *import* the certificate/key you have, into that keystore file.  To do this, you first create a PKCS#12 file from your `something.crt` and `something.key` files, and then import that PKCS#12 file into your keystore file (*e.g.* `/path/to/keystore.jks`) using the `keytool` command; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11954816/4072843 for examples of how to do this.  (Note that your `something.csr` file is **not** needed for this; the `.csr` extension suggests that that file is the [Certificate Signing Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) file, which is how you requested that certificate from your CA; a CSR file is not, in itself, a full certificate.)

Comment: Hi Castaglia, thanks this was helpful and sorry for the delay. seems like it works but i guess now the problem lies on the my server. I can't configure ssl ( bitbucket ). I'm still trying to figure out where the problem is.